# TYPO3. Extension "Indexed Search" in the header. How to exclude target page from search results?

Tags: search, typo3

The target page is excluded from search results in setup.typoscript. But in the results it appears.

The targetPid is 179.

setup.typoscript

```
lib.headerSearch = USER
lib.headerSearch {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = IndexedSearch
    pluginName = Pi2
    vendorName = TYPO3\CMS
    switchableControllerActions {
        Search {
enter image description here            1 = form
            2 = search
        }
    }
    features {
        requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0
    }
    view < plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Templates/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view.templateRootPath}
        20 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }

    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:indexed_search/Resources/Private/Partials/
        10 = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.view.partialRootPath}
        20 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Search/
    }

    partialRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/IndexedSearch/
        20 = EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Search/
    }
    
    settings =< plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings    
    settings.results.excludeUidList = 179
}
```

[excludeUidList exists in results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aallN.png)

And the result page is appears in the resultsets[-1].rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`excludeUidList` is a parameter that belongs to TypoScript `HMENU` but IIRC not to indexed search.

If you want to exclude a page from the search results, just go to the `behaviour` tab of the editing form of that page and click the `Include in Search[no_search]` switch

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, `excludeUidList` is a valid setting? I couldn't find it in the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/main/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html

indexed_search acts like a common crawler: so you can "hide" pages via meta-tag and page stettings:

```
page.meta {
  robots = INDEX,FOLLOW    
  robots.override = NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW 
  robots.override.if.isTrue.field = no_search 
}
```